# What will trigger a worst time search for a binary heap and what is the run time?

Tags: data-structures, heaps, priority-queues

I thought if the values in a max or min heap is monotonically increasing or decreasing, then this will trigger a worst case run time of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ because you will have to go through each and every single node to get to the value you want.

However, many sources state that heap has a worst case of $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ for (all?) transactions.

I don't see how you can do $n\log n$ for a monotonically increasing binary heap.

Can someone clarity?

Comment: You apparently don't know how heaps work. The neat thing is that it does *not* have to look at all entries due to well-chosen and maintained invariants.

Comment: Also, worst-case running time for *what operation*?  For a lookup?  To build the heap?  The running time depends on the operation you are doing.  You can't talk about "the running time for a heap" -- that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heaps are maintained so that they are always balanced. A heap containing $n$ elements will have height $O(\log n)$. All operations on heaps take time linear in the height.

Comment: doh! confused binary heap with binary tree